# How is Google's App indexing different from Facebook's App links?

Tags: android, facebook, applinks, android-app-indexing, google-search-platform

- Both of them seem to provide a way to add the concept of `urls` to native apps
- As far as I understand, Facebook tried to set a standard with App links for the problem
- I am not sure where does Google's app indexing diverges from the same idea

**Android App Indexing** says way to index app to map corresponding content on the web

where as

**App links** says app-to-app linking specific content

Both suggests, have a `url-like` structure to target specific content on apps to target from outside the app (may it another app or web)

What I want to find out:

- When creating my app should I do both or can app-links serve for both (since its a standard) or how to benefit from both ?

Comment: AFAIK, app indexing is specific to Android apps whereas app links is designed to be cross platform (with support for Android, iOS and Windows Phone).

Comment: Are you saying both do the exactly same thing, but 1 is android only and the other is a standard ?

Comment: No, there are more subtle technical differences. What I am pointing out is that App Indexing is geared towards Google search, and currently there's only support on Android. App Links was developed to have multi-platform support (including Android, but also iOS, Windows Phone, etc), and was designed for general app->app linking.

Comment: By the way, if you use branch.io to create links, the service automatically creates the Facebook AppLinks metatags AND the Google App Indexing metatags so you don't have to bother creating this yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement both.  [AppIndexing also now affects personalized search ranking](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.nz/2015/02/finding-more-mobile-friendly-search.html) , so it may yield better results for your Android users .

Quoted from page above in case the link rots:

> Starting today, we will begin to use information from indexed apps as
>   a factor in ranking for signed-in users who have the app installed. As
>   a result, we may now surface content from indexed apps more
>   prominently in search.

If you have a lot of audience on Android, I'd recommend using AppIndexing.  If you have a lot of users on Facebook, I'd recommend using App Links.  If you have both, do both!

To directly answer your question, you can't rely on App Links to fulfill AppIndexing, but you can probably do the work at the same time with minimal additional effort.

*Edit*

To better answer your question, you should be able to structure the expected URIs to be the same for both.  This would enable the handling of the Intent in the Android client to support both incoming AppLink URIs and AppIndexing URIs.

*Edit 2*

Example URI structure to support both AppIndexing and AppLinks.

Let's say you have an Android app called SuperLinks with the package name com.example.superlinks, you want to create a schema to address a specific resource, called examplelink #1234.  Your URI schema would be superlinks://examplelink/1234 which you could implement the Android client handling once, while adding the 2 differing pieces to the webpage's head.

Your AndroidManifest.xml would contain Intent filters to handle the schema you've created as such ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/server)):

`...
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="superlinks" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
...`

Note the action and category flags are necessary for the app to be listed as an option in the chooser when a user attempts to open one of your schema links.

To support AppIndexing, you'd add the following to your page's head ([Reference](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/server)):

`<head>
  ...
  <link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.example.superlinks/superlinks/examplelink/1234" />
  ...
</head>`

To support AppLinks, you'd add the following to your page's head [Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content):

`<head>
    ...
    <meta property="al:android:url" content="superlinks://examplelink/1234">
    <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.example.superlinks">
    <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="SuperLinks">
    ...
</head>`

Comment: Is there AppIndexing API for IOS devices or still Android only?

Comment: Still Android only at current, but with Google starting to use AppIndexing as a ranking signal, it could still have a boosting effect on overall search results, benefiting your iOS users as well.  There's nothing to stop you from attempting to redirect iOS users to your Schema, once on your page to essentially deep link them into your app anyway.

Comment: Your answer informs that AppIndexing is used to rank the search result.
Yes, you can do both (no doubt) but how is the intent different ?

Comment: Updating answer with more clarity on what I think you're asking.  You can structure the handling of incoming URIs to be the same, yes.

Comment: Can you add examples of both `App-index uri` vs `App link uri` ?

Comment: Answer updated with example URI supporting both AppIndexing and AppLinks.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement both.

You can actually have the same (or very very similar) code on the app side to handle the incoming link, but on your server side, you should implement both.

Comment: Whats the best next thing for IOS applications instead of AppIndexing

Comment: iOS has smart banners for Safari, but it's not quite the same as Google's app index.

Comment: Are you saying both do the exactly same thing, but 1 is android only and the other is a standard ?

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer hightlighting how are they different and how the usecase/considerations changes ?

Answer (score 0):

App Indexing lets Google index apps just like websites(on simple way Google app indexing register your application in google search engine). Deep links to your Android app appear in Google Search results, letting users get to your native mobile experience quickly, landing exactly on the right content within your app.

If your application registered on google indexing and you going to search on google search now then following thing happened:-

[image]

see this link :- https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/

This is the official [sample code](http://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/app-indexing#1) of app indexing.

App Indexing use for index your app in google index and whenever user search for your app content on google search then it shows your app link on google search.

**Note:-**

If you have a website then you must have to register from google developer console. (See video from [this](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) link and time is 2.50 sec)

Answer (score 0):

From an implementation perspective, the integration of these standards is basically the same. They are simple ways to turn your website into a link that also points to your app when relevant. To implement, you just add the appropriate metatags to your site.

For Google's App Indexing, it's just a `<link/>` tag like so:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="myapp://stuff?params=1&params=2"/>
```

For AppLinks, it's just custom Facebook tags like so:

```
<meta property="al:android:url" content="myapp://stuff?params=1&params=2" />
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.myapp.package" />
<meta property="al:android:app_name" content="My App" />
```

You basically have to implement both because Google and Facebook are viciously fighting for control over mobile eyeballs. Google would never use a Facebook standard and visa versa.

Functionally, they are quite different:

- Google's App Indexing will basically change your standard website page search result into an app page search result when you add the appropriate tags.
- Facebook's App Links are used by App Invites and the Ads product to determine how to open up the app. We haven't seen any other dramatic difference in linking when adding the tags though.

If you don't want to bother setting any of this up, check out [branch.io](https://branch.io) (a service I work on). We act as your website and automatically inject the correct metatags so you don't have to worry about any of this.